# JavaScript - Parse single variable in string

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Whats be best way to parse a single variable in a string without using `eval`?

I have strings as following:

```
"'myString'" -> should be a string with value "myString"
"true"       -> should be a boolean with value true
"12"         -> should be a number with value 12
```

This is working but I would like a more secure solution:

```
var parsedValue = eval(stringToParse);
```

Comment: Where are the `stringToParse` strings coming from? User input?

Comment: What should your function do with `"[123]"`? Or `"{f:5}"`?

Comment: It only need to handle string, boolean and number for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON.parse should do it, but you have to replace single quotes with doubles

```
JSON.parse("'myString'".replace(/'/g,'"'))
JSON.parse("true")
JSON.parse("12")
```

Comment: My bad. The replace might cause problems.